# This page cannot be displayed error when calling a long stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, database, stored-procedures, timeout

I am calling a stored procedure using ASP.Net page. The stored procedure takes a long time so I have set database command timeout property to 0 which means infinite. I have also set executionTimeout in web.config to 7200 which means 2 hours.

When stored procedure is called from that page, after a long time it throws error:

> This page can't be displayed

[image]

I have written try catch block and set break point but it doesn't come inside catch.

How do I fix this issue?

**EDIT**

```
Here's the code:

try
{
//database is Sybase
ConnectionOpenedHere();
AseCommand command = new AseCommand();
command.Connection = con;
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandTimeout = 0;
//some more code here
command.CommandText = storedProcedure;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();    //The code doesn't go beyond this line and shows error after a long time
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

**EDIT**

Finally able to catch the exception. Here's the error:

> Error: Connection to Sybase server has been lost. All active
>   transactions have been rolled back
>
> Stack Trace:   at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseCommand.CheckResult(Int32
>   res)    at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseCommand.Execute()    at
>   Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   MyWebsite.Database.MyStoredProcedure(Int32 subtype, string idno)

There is no Inner Exception.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code

Comment: This is most likely caused by the browser giving up on waiting for the page to respond. Some re-engineering would probably be called for. It's not reasonable to have the browser wait 2 hours for the response...

Comment: Question edited and code added

Comment: How long your SP takes ?

Comment: At least 1 hour 30 minutes.

Comment: Why ? I mean why have you such a long time taking SP. i guess you need to rethink the logic of your `SP` or may be `application`. Can u add SP code here if its not too long ?

Comment: The SP is HUGE so cannot post here. It performs a lot of operations. I have edited my post and pasted the error I am getting.

Comment: I guess you really need to change the logic of your application. Can u describe what is your application and what does your SP do ?

Comment: The SP gets data from many different tables and inserts record into another set of tables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80270/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-frank-martin).

Comment: Check with My Answer -

Comment: I have made those changes and ran the application. Will post update here when it's done.

Comment: Dang, it turns out the error is actually in the database server itself. I ran that SP directly in database and even there it didn't run and showed error after two hours. The error is caused by something to do with transaction log which is full.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution in your web.config file. Hope this will works. It will hold execution extended till your Store Procedure runs..

But your Store Procedure must be perfect.

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="9999" /> 
</appSettings>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <System.Web>
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
  </System.Web>
 <sessionState timeout="10000"/>
```

And Add Machine Key also